# retrieve json value in php

Tags: php, json

I am retrieving JSON data from RESTful API as follows:

```
 //manipute json

{
  "email": "robert@gmail.com",
  "phone": "123456789",
  "address": {
    "line1": "2/15 street",
    "line2": "Lonsdale",

  },

  "extrafields": [
    {
      "key": "firstname",
      "value": "Robert"
    },
    {
      "key": "lastname",
      "value": "Allen"
    },

  ],

}

$obj=json_decode($output); //$output the retrieved JSON which is decoded in php 

// Code below works fine to get the "email" value
    $s = $obj->{'email'};

// Code below works fine to get the line1 of "address"  
    $s = $obj->address->{'line1'};
```

please help me with the code to retrieve value of key= "firstname"

Answer (score 0):

Too bad the extra fields are stored in this way, and not as:

```
extrafields {
  "firstname": "Robert",
  "lastname": "Allen"
}
```

That would have made more sense and you could easily read the extra fields like so:

```
$firstname = $obj->extrafields->firstname;
```

**But...**

In your case it is possible as well, but you will need a loop to do it right.

```
$extrafields = $obj->extrafields;

$firstname = '';
foreach ($extrafields as $extrafield)
{
  if ($extrafield->key == 'firstname')
  {
    $firstname = $extrafield->value;
    break;
  }
}
```

Strictly you don't need the loop in this specific case, but nothing guarantees you that firstname will always be the first extra field. So for safety you have to check the key.

Answer (score -1):

You can use json_decode() to retrieve data to array

```
$array = json_decode($output, true);
```

When you can use:

```
echo $array['email']; // output: robert@gmail.com
echo $array['extrafields'][0]['key']; //output firstname
```

Or to object:

```
$object = json_decode($output);

echo $object->email;  // output: robert@gmail.com
echo $object->extrafields[0]->key; //output firstname
```

Comment: This reads the key of the first extra field instead of the value that goes with the key 'firstname'. They are coincidentally the same, but it's not reliable to assume such a thing.